# How to securely verify user requests

Tags: security, web

I'm building a basic website where a logged in user makes requests to a server. What are some good practices for the server to verify that the user is who he says he is? Right now I create a session key every time the user logs in which is then stored in the DB. the session key is the hash of the users username concatenated with the current time. Every time the user makes a request he sends along the session key to be verified. Are there any security flaws with this method?

Comment: Search for "session hijacking".

Comment: This might be more suitable for security.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this isn't real security. It is know as [Security by Obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity).

If an attacker wants to hijack a session, all they would have to do is hash the username along with the time and set it as their cookie value. Of course this would have to correspond with a valid user session being logged on at that time, but they could easily script this.

For example, if they wanted to log on as `bob@example.com` the could simply generate the hash of `bob@example.com:00:00:00`, `bob@example.com:00:00:01`, `bob@example.com:00:00:02`, etc, etc, until they find a session value that allows them to access privileged pages.

Comment: True but wouldn't the attacker not know that I'm using a hash of the username and the current time concatenated? Theoretically I could be using any string.

Comment: @Nate Security by Obscurity is not real security - it is akin to hiding your door key under the plantpot because nobody knows it is there. A secure system has to hold up to scrutiny and be secure even if the mechanisms and algorithms are known to the attacker. What if your system goes Open Source, or the attacker manages to access your source code (they might have purchased your system themselves, there might be a source disclosure vulnerability elsewhere) or somebody posts on the internet how it works (such as here on this question) - your whole security model is taken down in one fell swoop.